# How to write a script to move files from one FTP server to another?

Tags: windows-vista, ssh, ftp, script, batch

What are some good ways to move file from a development site on a linux server to another linux server (which would be production). I will be working from a Vista system. Basically, I'd like to just doubleclick a batch file or something along those lines to initiate the copy. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can script Windows command-line FTP and put it in a batch/cmd file.  See [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/96269) and [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555976) for detailed instructions.

Answer (score 0):

from the dev server:

```
$rsync avz /path/to/your/content otherserver:/path/to/your/content
```

set up ssh public keys and it will copy without a password. many linux distros have a script ssh-copy-id which automates this:

```
$ssh-copy-id otherserver
```

Comment: Now would I be able to trigger this by a batch file on my local Vista system?